# mmetric could not find function R

Tags: r, naivebayes

I have library(rminer) installed yet wondering why mmertric is still not there and unable to use the function.

Anyone has come across this?

```
#probability of each landmass category
flagdmodel <- naiveBayes(landmass ~ ., data=trainfdata)
#flagdmodel

#predictionmodel
flagprediction <- predict(flagdmodel, testfdata)
mmetric(testfdata$landmass, flagprediction, c("ACC","PRECISION","TPR","F1"))
+ mmetric(testfdata$landmass, flagprediction, c("ACC","PRECISION","TPR","F1"))
```

> mmetric()
>   Error in mmetric() : could not find function "mmetric"
>   mmetric()
>   Error in mmetric() : could not find function "mmetric"

Comment: are you sure rminer is loaded and not just installed?  When you look at the output of `search()` is there an element `"package:rminer"`?

Comment: loaded? sorry im using Rstudio, i have installed it the traditional way via tools-> install packages

Answer (score 2):

Question: why can't R find functions for the package I installed with RStudio's install tool?

Answer: 
When you want to use functions or other objects in packages that aren't in `R`, you need to do two things:

1. `install.packages("rminer")`
2. `library(rminer)`

RStudio can do the first step for you with the install tool, but you still need to do the second one. The first step installs the needed directories and files on your computer. The second step loads them into your current R environment.

In RStudio, you can use the packages tab to check both steps. Installed packages will be in the list in that tab. Loaded packages will have a checkmark to the left of the package name.

It may be easier to find, though if you just run the following in your console:

`"package:rminer" %in% search()`

If the output is `TRUE` you're good to go. If it's `FALSE` you need to run `library(rminer)`